# Contextual meaning of 'sought to legitimize the city's social strivings by evoking a history the city did not truly posses'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, context

This sentence below was a GRE question and the two *italics* and **bold** words are the actual answers to the text completion. Still, I do not understand what the sentence is trying to say. My understanding is below that.

> The architects of New York's early skyscrapers, hinting here at a
> twelfth-century cathedral, there at a fifteenth-century palace,
> sought to legitimize the city's social strivings by ***evoking*** a history the city did not truly ***possess***.

I understand that they sought to validate the 'social strivings throughout history' by making the buildings look very old and that those buildings evoke a sense of emotion about that period.

But why does it say *'a history the city did not truly possess'*? If it's history then ofcourse it did happen in that city, so why wouldn't it truly possess that history?

Also, does *'hinting here at a twelfth-century cathedral'* mean that the buildings **indirectly** makes the people think about these 'old' style buildings?

Comment: Please do not use comments to answer questions. If you have an answer, write it in the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

New York developed from a Dutch settlement (New Amsterdam) in the 17th century.

The passage says that early skyscrapers featured architectural styles imitating older buildings such as 12th century cathedrals and 15th century palaces, to make the inhabitants feel as though their city had a much longer history than it really did. Architects hoped to give New York something of the style of a European city (that would have genuine ancient buildings).

Comment: It might help to add the silent connector *that*: "A history (that) the city did not truly possess."